# Promoting a domain controller fails prerequisites

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain, domain-controller, window-server-2019

I'm replacing my domain controller with another domain controller with more efficient hardware and migrate from Server 2012 R2 to Windows Server 2019.

The first step I joined the new server to the domain. Then promoting the server to a domain controller shows this error:

> Verification of prerequisites for Active Directory preparation failed.

> Unable to verify whether schema master has completed a replication cycle after last reboot. Exception: Unavailable Critical Extension.

> Server extended error: 8366. Server extended message: 000020AE:
> SvcErr: DSID-0321040C, problem 5010 (UNAVAIL_EXTENSION), data 8610 .
> Adprep failed to verify whether schema master has completed a
> replication cycle after last reboot. [Status/Consequence] The schema
> is not upgraded. [User Action] Check the log file ADPrep.log in the
> C:\Windows\debug\adprep\logs\20231105012425-test directory for
> possible cause of failure.

Upon searching I found that I have residual for an older domain controller.

[steps remove domain controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO95J.png)

I followed these steps and couldn't delete it.

I went to Active Directory Sites and Services to check and delete, which showed:

> Windows cannot delete object LDAP://... because: A referral was
> returned from the server.

[image: Active Directory Sites and Services]

i can't delete server PRIME-PACS at all

**How can I resolve this problem to add a new domain controller?**

Comment: welcome, I don't get the point. did you already (successfully) joined a SDC to the PDC or not?

Comment: No, I can't promote a new domain to an existing domain till now
but I could join the domain to the the existing domain controller

Comment: Sounds like your domain structure is still at a level too low for 2019 to support and it can't be upgraded due to replication issues. These need to be fixed first. Have you successfully transferred the FSMO roles to another server  that's still there (schema master, domain name master, infrastructure master, RID master, PDC emulator)?

Comment: Yes all the fsmo belongs to the only one domain controller 
i ran netdom query fsmo
all the roles belong to
RosenfieldAD.office.rosenfielddwc.com

Comment: What research ash been done? i dont see here any afford - like [Microsoft Tutorial](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/step-by-step-manually-removing-a-domain-controller-server/ba-p/280564) [Serverfault 1088120](https://serverfault.com/questions/1088120/how-to-properly-and-completely-remove-a-windows-domain-controller) [Serverfault 550689](https://serverfault.com/questions/550689/safely-demote-a-domain-controller?rq=1)
and a ton more - did you read that before posting?

Comment: I just can't join a domain controller to an existing domain controller

Comment: This is the replication status for the following directory partition on this directory server. 
 
Directory partition:
DC=RHealth,DC=office,DC=rosenfielddwc,DC=com 
This directory server has not recently received replication information from a number of directory servers.  The count of directory servers is shown, divided into the following intervals. 
it shows this error message that, the domain no longer exists and i won't to stop the replication and delete anything related to DC=Rhealth

Answer (score 1):

Try a replication using the command line and see what happens

`repadmin /syncall /AdeP`

Comment: PS C:\Users\Administrator> repadmin /syncall /AdeP
Syncing all NC's held on RosenfieldAD.
Syncing partition: DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=office,DC=rosenfielddwc,DC=com
CALLBACK MESSAGE: Error contacting server CN=NTDS Settings,CN=PRIME-PACS,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=office,DC=rosenfielddwc,DC=com (network
error): 1722 (0x6ba):
    The RPC server is unavailable.
CALLBACK MESSAGE: SyncAll Finished.

SyncAll reported the following errors:
Error contacting server CN=NTDS Settings,CN=PRIME-PACS,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Config etc

Comment: Can you please provide the full output in a pastebin. That RPC error is worrying and worth investigating